# Uploading Files tutorial

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm learning this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

In my IDE StorageProperties is underlined red. But in the tutorial, if I'm not mistaken there is no file StorageProperties. Could you tell me whether it is possible to follow this tutorial or it is practically impossible?

[image]

Comment: The project works without errors: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files

Comment: @Simon Martinelli, I can't understand you. Could you tell me what part of the tutorial I missed. The tutorial's project is generated from scratch, but wedon't create StorageProperties. We are trying to use it.

Comment: You have to create it. My link is the link to the repository with the code that is used in the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StorageProperties.java is present here https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files/blob/main/complete/src/main/java/com/example/uploadingfiles/storage/StorageProperties.java

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("storage")
public class StorageProperties {

    /**
     * Folder location for storing files
     */
    private String location = "upload-dir";

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

I hope this solves your query.